# Need a help with adjustable DC power supply

Tags: power-supply, voltage, ground

I just purchased an adjustable DC power supply.

[https://www.amazon.com/Variable-Eventek-Adjustable-Regulated-Alligator/dp/B07DQR177D](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B07DQR177D)
[image]
It has three terminals : "-"(black), "ground"(green) and "+"(red).

When I test it with multi-meter, there is no voltage between the negative rail and the ground rail. Same for the voltage between the ground rail and the positive rail.

When I connect the negative rail and the positive rail together, it works correctly.
However, this is not why I bought an adjustable DC supply with **3 terminals**.

I bought it so that I can use operational amplifiers...

**What would the purpose of this ground terminal?**

Is there a way that I can use this adjustable DC power supply as I want to use it?

Comment: When you say you want to power opamps, do you mean split power supply as in +-12 V? If yes, then you need a dual power supply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The green terminal is true earth ground. It is connected to the ground lug on the ac power cord, which should ultimately be connected to a ground rod. The output of the power supply would seem to be **isolated** from ground, meaning that neither the positive or negative terminal is connected to ground.

For work with operational amplifiers you probably want a symmetrical bipolar power supply, which outputs both a positive and negative voltage having the same magnitude. Both of these voltages are with respect to a third common output. Such a supply would likely have four terminals where the fourth was the green earth ground.

Comment: Thank you Elliot.  I was thinking about the same thing about the symmetrical bipolar power supply. I guess I would have to return this one then.

Comment: @user167987 it's a fair assumption that this power supply's outputs are isolated from mains. As a result, rather than returning it, you could buy a second one and wire them up appropriately :) up to you but.

Comment: @DSWG Yeah. That's what I am trying to do but this one is 50€ more expensive than the one with 2 terminals... So I am returning it to get a cheaper one :)